# C++ AccessLog Parser using MMap/OpenMP - Problem with counting media stream web-access events correcty

Tags: openmp, logparser

Hello and first of all sorry if the problem description sounds strange and inprecise. It's not that easy for me to describe my complex problem in english, but I hope you will understand what I mean.

I made a CLI-tool for parsing Webserver Access Logs. I focussed on performance and flexibility in usage.

Therefore I use MMap to read LogFiles into Memory and then I pass the memory mapped char* to a parallel OpenMP processing loop.

In the omp parallel for loop I just parse the several informative substrings from every single LogString using boost::regex_search and I store the event-data in a thread-local custom LogEvent-type Object.

After creating this LogEvent-Object from the current string, I append the LogEvent to a vector and proceed with parsing the next String and so on.

The tricky thing is that I parse a user configuration file on program start. The user can define multiple "data-fields" by specifying a Field-name and a RegEx that will match the data.

E.g.:

```
Time = \d{2}\/\w{3}\/\d{4}
IP = \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}
Object = \d{2,8}\_w\d{1,3}.mp4|\d{2,10}.flv
```

Further the user can specify the order that the output report data will be generated

E.g.:

```
field_0 = %IP%
field_1 = %Object%
field_2 = %Time%
```

The output strings could look like:

```
10.20.30.1;video_xyz.flv;Jul/23/2011:11:12;3 
10.20.30.1;video_xyz.flv;Jul/23/2011:11:17;1 
10.20.30.1;video_xyz.flv;Jul/23/2011:11:18;12
10.11.30.1;video_xyz.blabla.mp4;Jul/23/2011:11:12;3
```

The problem I have is, that streaming a video-file causes several access events in the log. I cannot really recognize someone just reloading/buffering the stream because different client platform have different kind of behaviour at generating server response codes.

Right now I count events multiple times which is often wrong.

How can I handle this problem? It's pretty general I know, but if you think about my programm and how I described it, you will soon see the problem is hard to solve with my program design.

I found the one or another way to workaround but it always is a really bad performance impact and not a legit solution.

Somehow I must avoid to append those LogEvents to the vector of LogEvent-Objects at parsing time because until that point the strings are still in the correct chronological order so I can compare the current string with the previous and so on.

After that point the omp critical phase begins and the thread local results are combined and if I want to check for wrong multiple hit counts, I will have to search through the whole data array which is nogo.

I hope my problem is clear enough. Any Ideas? (dunno if sample code would help, because it's more a problem of design i think)...

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I found a workaround that I can live with for a while.

While parsing the strings I always grab the IP address and the target item from every logstring now.

I have a thread local map that stores IP-Adress as key and Target Item (e.g. Video Stream) as value.

whenever I want to count a logevent I check before, if the currently processed LogsStrings's IP Adress is already a Key of my thread local Map.

If it's not, it's safe to count the event. And I add the current IP as key and Object as value which means I update the last accessed object for this specific IP.

If it is already a key of my map, I check if this key's value (the target item) is identical with my current LogStrings Target.

If so, that can just mean that the last time this user accessed anything on my server was when accessing the same video stream.

I will only continue to count events from this IP adress, when the object has changed.

Because it is very unlikely that a user switches from one stream to another and then back (even if he would it would be correct to count it) so it looks like we got a new event here, that we really want to count.

This works somehow like reversed greylisting. any ip is just counted once and then blocked from counting until a new signature is generated because of the new object.

Of course this is a performance impact too so if you have any better ideas, feel free to answer:P